# listing multiple files for a merge (arc)python

Tags: arcpy, merge, error-999999, list

I have created a script to convert GPX into features with python. This script works but now I want to add all these separate feature classes (point features) in one featureclass/layer and convert it into a line feature. The following is the coding I did to merge the layers.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
MergeFolder = "D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\Geo_data.gdb"
Total = "D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output\total"
arcpy.env.workspace =MergeFolder

Mylist= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type= "point")

arcpy.Merge_management (Mylist, Total)
```

The following Error occurs;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/scripts/Merge.py", line 13, in 
>       arcpy.Merge_management (Mylist, Total)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4124, in
>   Merge
>       raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (Merge).

I think the listing is the problem since no error occurs if I replace the Mylist with the actual filenames of the converted GPX files. Does anyone know how I should change my way of listing (or use some other function/command to select a huge amount of files).

Filling in/ using some function for finding the right names is not possible since the names have nothing in common.

Comment: Start by adding an r in front of the paths, for example: r"D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\Geo_data.gdb"

Comment: It did do something. Now i have the following error;

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/scripts/Merge.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.Merge_management (Mylist, Total)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4124, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output\total
Failed to execute (Merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layer paths need the preceding "r" if your using back slashes alternatively you may use forward slashes "/" instead.  Also the second parameter of the merge method needs to be a feature class, not just a directory, try:

> Merge_management (inputs, output, {field_mappings})

```
MergeFolder = r"D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\Geo_data.gdb"
Total = r"D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output.gdb\myMergeLayer"
```

OR

```
MergeFolder = "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/Geo_data.gdb"
Total = "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/output.gdb/myMergeLayer"
```

Also, you have a space in the merge statement between the "t" in managemen"t" and the first parentheses, use:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(Mylist, Total)
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/scripts/Merge.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.Merge_management (Mylist, Total)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4124, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output\total\myMerge.shp
Failed to execute (Merge).

Comment: I also tried to use the following directory;
Total = r"D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output\total.shp

Since the output is a geodatabase and the total was an existing feature layer in which I wanted to merge the GPX files in. Maybe a cause of the error could be because the the output is in a different geodatabase?

Comment: I seem to get the following error;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Altwym_2017/programmeren/scripts/Merge.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.Merge_management(Mylist, Total)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4124, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output\myMerge.shp
Failed to execute (Merge).

Comment: The output currently is looking for a directory called "output" located D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren, does the "output" directory exist?

Comment: yes the output directory exists, it is a geodatabase

Comment: try this then, r'D:\Altwym_2017\programmeren\output.gdb\myMergeLayer', you need to include the .gdb extension in the fc path since output is a gdb not a directory.